# Распаковка баз данных на Linux

Tags: резервное-копирование, linux

Есть backup базы данных с расширением .gbk. Подскажите, пожалуста, как распаковать его?

Answer (score 1):

видимо выполнив команду `gbak <options> -user <username> -password <password> <source> 
<destination>`
подробнее [тут](http://www.destructor.de/firebird/gbak.htm)

Comment: опции нужно выставлять исходя из того, что вам нужно. примеры с применением опций и их описание есть в документации.

Comment: Там везде написано где бекап с расширеннием .fbk.
А подскажите, пожалуйста, как распаковать с расширение .gbk?

Comment: вот тут http://www.ibase.ru/devinfo/gbak.htm описание на русском. Там все описано.

Comment: вот еще http://www.opennet.ru/base/sys/firebird_backup.txt.html